# Weird and complex puzzle that we need help with

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, enigmatic-puzzle

So basically this is a complex deep web puzzle and we're pretty much stuck at it right now as we don't have any idea what this is about, any help will be aprreciated (the attached images are the translations from the puzzles language)[image: First part]

[image: Second part]

Comment: Is there something more to this? It seems to end quite abruptly: "Not bound to"...

Comment: theres also a song, its on this site http://cu3aj5u7fz67vqmy.onion//R2FpYQ==/IENyb251cw==/Wrath.html
Possibly we may have to find another page but currently this is all weve got to work with.
(If you can't access the .onion link use the surface web mirror http://redtrianglemirror.cf/ and click on Wrath, past chapters may be related but usually tend to be linear and have an unique solution of their own.

Comment: Could you tell us more about where this puzzle comes from? Thanks.

Comment: As far as I understand, the "whole" must be the sum of the rightmost numbers (following the point).

Comment: Could you also confirm that this puzzle is not currently being used as part of an active competition?

Comment: To Gareth, it's a puzzle from the deep web, we don't know where it's from we just got it from nowhere and it's been a fun ride until now, cause were stuck haha, there doesn't seem to be any recruitment involved, it's most likely just for knowledge

Comment: To gparyani: the puzzle is not a competition, theres not a set countdown or anything, us, a big team of solvers have been working very hard on this but are still lost on this (were the only solving group)

Comment: Thanks. Next time, please make sure to use the @-notification (e.g. "@Zyu") to ensure that users are notified of your comments. I was not notified of your response to my comment and didn't see it until I navigated here.

Comment: Oh lmao sure @gparyani , so you got any ideas on what this could be?

Comment: some of the terminology (except for: "corntinue") seems like talk about hard disk drive stuff.  Maybe some work on torsion, rotational inertia, latency, etc...  the info provided is too incomplete to conclude

Answer (score 1):

Answer can be -

> hey guys if you inspect the element while the song is playing, you will find a process called 403 expanded knowledge which will bring you to a page that only shows the song playing by itself in an audio file, which if you speed it up sounds better but if you slow it down, you can hear that the chords are playing twice and the notes by themselves play once anyway.
> I hope this information helps solve this mystery

Comment: Welcome to Puzzling.SE, Do take the [tour](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/tour) to familiarize yourself with the site as well as Can you give proper explanation as of how it is the answer you gave. Please explain each line in its reference. Try putting the spoiler tag in your answer.